# What is the best way to find all occurrences of values from one dataframe in another dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, lookup-tables, pyspark

I am working on a spark cluster and I have two dataframes. One contains text. The other is a look-up table. Both tables are huge (M and N both could easily exceed 100,000 entries). What is the best way to match them?

Doing a cross-join then filtering results based on matches seems like a crazy idea since I would most certainly run out of memory.

My dataframes look something like this:

```
df1:

        text
0       i like apples
1       oranges are good
2       eating bananas is healthy
.       ...
.       ...
M       tomatoes are red, bananas are yellow

df2:

        fruit_lookup
0       apples
1       oranges
2       bananas
.       ...
.       ...
N       tomatoes
```

I am expecting an output dataframe to look something like this:

```
output_df:

        text                                     extracted_fruits
0       i like apples                            ['apples']
1       oranges are good                         ['oranges']
2       eating bananas is healthy                ['bananas']
.       ...
.       ...
M       tomatoes are red, bananas are yellow .   ['tomatoes','bananas']
```

Comment: What version of spark?

Comment: I have two clusters. One with Spark 1.6 and the other is 2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use **[CountVectorizerModel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel)** as 100K lookup words should be manageable for this model (default *vocabSize=262144*):

The basic idea is to create the **CountVectorizerModel** based on a customized list from `df2` (lookup table). split `df1.text` into an array column and then transform this column into a SparseVector which can then be mapped into words:

**Edit:** in *split* function , adjusted the regex from `\s+` to `[\s\p{Punct}]+` so that all punctuation marks are removed. change `'text'` to `lower(col('text'))`  if the lookup is case insensitive.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizerModel
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, udf, regexp_replace, lower

df2.show()                                                                                                   
+---+------------+
| id|fruit_lookup|
+---+------------+
|  0|      apples|
|  1|     oranges|
|  2|     bananas|
|  3|    tomatoes|
|  4|dragon fruit|
+---+------------+
```

**Edit-2:** Added the following df1 pre-process step and create an array column including all N-gram combinations. For each string with `L` words, N=2 will add `(L-1)` more items in array, if N=3, `(L-1)+(L-2)` more items.

```
# max number of words in a single entry of the lookup table df2
N = 2

# Pre-process the `text` field up to N-grams, 
# example: ngram_str('oranges are good', 3) 
#      --> ['oranges', 'are', 'good', 'oranges are', 'are good', 'oranges are good']
def ngram_str(s_t_r, N):
  arr = s_t_r.split()           
  L = len(arr)           
  for i in range(2,N+1):           
    if L - i < 0: break           
    arr += [ ' '.join(arr[j:j+i]) for j in range(L-i+1) ]           
  return arr           

udf_ngram_str = udf(lambda x: ngram_str(x, N), 'array<string>')

df1_processed = df1.withColumn('words_arr', udf_ngram_str(lower(regexp_replace('text', r'[\s\p{Punct}]+', ' '))))
```

Implement the model on the processed df1:

```
lst = [ r.fruit_lookup for r in df2.collect() ]

model = CountVectorizerModel.from_vocabulary(lst, inputCol='words_arr', outputCol='fruits_vec')

df3 = model.transform(df1_processed)
df3.show(20,40)
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------+
#|                                    text|                               words_arr|         fruits_vec|
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------+
#|                           I like apples|  [i, like, apples, i like, like apples]|      (5,[0],[1.0])|
#|                        oranges are good|[oranges, are, good, oranges are, are...|      (5,[1],[1.0])|
#|               eating bananas is healthy|[eating, bananas, is, healthy, eating...|      (5,[2],[1.0])|
#|    tomatoes are red, bananas are yellow|[tomatoes, are, red, bananas, are, ye...|(5,[2,3],[1.0,1.0])|
#|                                    test|                                  [test]|          (5,[],[])|
#|I have dragon fruit and apples in my bag|[i, have, dragon, fruit, and, apples,...|(5,[0,4],[1.0,1.0])|
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Then you can map the fruits_vec back to the fruits using `model.vocabulary`

```
vocabulary = model.vocabulary
#['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas', 'tomatoes', 'dragon fruit']

to_match = udf(lambda v: [ vocabulary[i] for i in v.indices ], 'array<string>')

df_new = df3.withColumn('extracted_fruits', to_match('fruits_vec')).drop('words_arr', 'fruits_vec')
df_new.show(truncate=False)                                      
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------+
#|text                                    |extracted_fruits      |
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------+
#|I like apples                           |[apples]              |
#|oranges are good                        |[oranges]             |
#|eating bananas is healthy               |[bananas]             |
#|tomatoes are red, bananas are yellow    |[bananas, tomatoes]   |
#|test                                    |[]                    |
#|I have dragon fruit and apples in my bag|[apples, dragon fruit]|
#+----------------------------------------+----------------------+
```

**Method-2:** As your dataset are not huge in terms of Spark context, the following might work, this will work with lookup value having multiple words as per your comment:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr, collect_set

df1.alias('d1').join(
      df2.alias('d2')
    , expr('d1.text rlike concat("\\\\b", d2.fruit_lookup, "\\\\b")')
    , 'left'
).groupby('text') \
 .agg(collect_set('fruit_lookup').alias('extracted_fruits')) \
 .show()
+--------------------+-------------------+                                      
|                text|   extracted_fruits|
+--------------------+-------------------+
|    oranges are good|          [oranges]|
|       I like apples|           [apples]|
|tomatoes are red,...|[tomatoes, bananas]|
|eating bananas is...|          [bananas]|
|                test|                 []|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Where: `"\\\\b` is word boundary so that the lookup values do not mess up with their contexts.

**Note:** you may need to clean up all punctuation marks and redundant spaces on both columns before the dataframe join.

Comment: Looks good except if the lookup table has entries with multiple words. (e.g. dragon fruit). What do you suggest in that case? Should I also split my lookup?

Comment: Another way is to join two dataframe using array_contains() or `rlike` and then groupby+collect_set, using `rlike` can resolve this problem in one shoot though it might be slow, just my initial thought as of now.

Comment: @tooskoolforkool,  if the max number of words in all entries is 2-3, it might be doable by using something similar to ngram to set up `words-arr` column. In fact, above this number, i.e. 3, we can setup separate routine to handle them and then join the result back, i suppose this could be a much smaller dataset for entries with more than 3 words.